# How do I get Visual Studio to build assembler from separate files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, x86-64, assembly

Due to the lack of compiler support for inline assembler with 64 bit targets, I have need to build it in separate files.

I have VS 2010 Professional, how can I set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `yasm` via its very own [vs integration mechanisms](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/vsyasm.html).

Basically, it comes down to installing an extra tool as an assembler in the VS settings files etc; however, the YASM team have done it for you which is incredibly useful.

Comment: I can't find the "Yasm Assembler" option anywhere in the properties dialog as described in that page. I have properly installed yasm before as I've compiled mpir and mpfr, yet I can't get the thing to work on my own projects...

Comment: Okay I figured it out. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Funny, I got the idea from the developer (B Gladman) who wrote the Windows .vcproj files for mpir. Glad you got it fixed.